Experience editor error for singleLineText
I'm encountering issues in Sitecore Experience Editor
while using the following Scriban code in a rendering:
{{sc_field Child "Latitude"}}

Below is the error
{"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"Edit the related item","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/cubes.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/cubes_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the related item in the Content Editor.","type":"common"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:personalize({command:\"webedit:personalize\"})","header":"Personalize","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/users_family.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/users_family_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Create or edit personalization for this component.","type":"sticky"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:editvariations({command:\"webedit:editvariations\"})","header":"Edit variations","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/windows.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/windows_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the variations.","type":"sticky"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{DED6C510-D3EA-4C19-90E7-229FCE9375AF}?lang=en&ver=1","

While using below code in cshtml file
@Html.Sitecore().Field("WatchNowCTAText", Model.DataSourceItem)

Below is the error
{"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"Edit the related item","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/cubes.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/cubes_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the related item in the Content Editor.","type":"common"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:personalize({command:\"webedit:personalize\"})","header":"Personalize","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/users_family.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/users_family_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Create or edit personalization for this component.","type":"sticky"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:editvariations({command:\"webedit:editvariations\"})","header":"Edit variations","icon":"/temp/iconcache/office/16x16/windows.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/windows_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the variations.","type":"sticky"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{B85A2EC3-4529-46DA-AEEC-9DCE40AA21ED}?lang=en&amp;ver=2","custom":{},"displayName":"Watch Now CTA","expandedDisplayName":null}

Is this a known error? I can't find anything related to this issue. Should I raise this issue with Sitecore?

This section is wrapped with scChromeData section and is hidden by default. It is used for editing the fields in the experience editor.

Can you check you are getting the html as above inside the experience editor and there is no custom css added which is displaying this section.
Hope this helps!!!

display: none was getting overridden. Thanks
